# just one record per group on each line

Tags: awk, ksh

let's say I have a following file named groups.txt containing:

```
aaa:
bbb:11,22
ccc:
ddd:44,11
```

I need to write a ksh command / script to display every record for every corresponding group just once pre row.
Expected result:

```
aaa:
bbb:11
bbb:22
ccc:
ddd:44
ddd:11
```

Any suggestion is more than welcome

I have already tried:

```
cat group | cut -d ":" -f 1,4| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' |  sed 's/:/ /g' | while read -r L11 L12
do {
 for L21 in $(echo $L12 | cut -d " " -f 1,2 | sed 's/,/ /g')
 do
  echo $L11, $L21
 done
} < /dev/null
done
```

but not working as expected. This command doesn't diplay the 'empty' groups

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with sed :

```
cat script.sed 
:A
  s/(^[^:]*:)([^,]*),(.*)/\1\2\n\1\3/
tA

sed -E -f script.sed infile
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a trivial task for awk:

```
awk -F '[:,]' -v OFS=':' '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $1, $i }' file
```

An empty group (`aaa:`) is also parsed into two fields; 1st is group name, 2nd is an empty string. So empty groups are printed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only).

```
awk -F':' '{gsub(/,/,ORS $1 ":")} 1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F':' '{gsub(/,/,ORS $1 FS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
aaa:
bbb:11
bbb:22
ccc:
ddd:44
ddd:11
```

Comment: That would fail if `$1` contained backreferences, e.g. `&`. Always be extremely careful if you're considering using input data as part of a regexp or replacement text - it's almost always the wrong approach due to insidious edge cases like this.